# how can I turn verify image of binary code from api to png by js

Tags: javascript, image

I try to put the verify image api into browser straightly, any I found code like below picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWo4R.jpg)

And use this code with 'data:image/png;base64' then I can get this verify image picture, and also I try to put api url into src of element ,but I still willing to get the response data and show it so that server side can do less, now the issue is when I call this api request, I got response data like below picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD7en.jpg)

Something like gibberish! Can anyone help me figure out?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should set `xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";` in your xhr request and then make blob object

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/mfuu7uz5/1/)

Comment: Thank you for you example, I put it into $.ajax and it's working!